# Regular expression to match opposite of: each .pdf under a file path containing a string. do not match folders

Tags: regex

Updated:

Sorry this is a bit difficult to explain and summarize, but I am dealing with a system that can only EXCLUDE items based on regex applied to the entire file path & individual filename. My desire is to have it INCLUDE only pdf files if they are contained in a folder or subfolder of "e-comps". Because it can only exclude, we would want to match all files (assuming they have a file extension) if they are not in a path containing "e-comps", as well as any file other than .pdf in a path containing "e-comps". Because it also passes on the file name by itself we should not match any item that does not contain a slash.

example input:

```
/client
/client/100-300
/client/100-300/101 abc
/client/100-300/101 abc/active
/client/100-300/101 abc/active/asset.pdf
/client/100-300/101 abc/active/asset.doc
/client/100-300/101 abc/e-comps/asset.pdf
/client/100-300/101 abc/e-comps/asset.doc
/client/100-300/101 abc/e-comps/asset.jpg
/client/100-300/101 abc/e-comps/folder/asset.jpg
/client/100-300/101 abc/e-comps/folder/asset.pdf
client
100-300
101 abc
active
asset.pdf
asset.doc
asset.jpg
```

should match:

```
/client/100-300/101 abc/active/asset.pdf
/client/100-300/101 abc/active/asset.doc
/client/100-300/101 abc/e-comps/asset.doc
/client/100-300/101 abc/e-comps/asset.jpg
/client/100-300/101 abc/e-comps/folder/asset.jpg
```

I have tried a regex based on the .pdf extension, but once i try to add anything regarding "e-comps" i get undesirable results. im a bit over my head here with regex - hoping someone knows some magic!

`^.+(?=\.)(?!\.pdf).*$`

i believe i am working with PCRE

Thank you!

Comment: You could also try [`^(?:(?!e-comps\/.*\.pdf$).)+[^\/]$`](https://regex101.com/r/HZvkkV/1)

Comment: @onyambu indeed it does!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCRE2:

```
^                # At the beginning of string
(?!              # match something that is not
  (\/[^\/]+)*    # 0+ subfolders
  \/e-comps      # followed by '/e-comps'
  (\/[^\/]+)*    # then 0 or more subfolders
  [^\/]*\.pdf$   # then ends with a PDF file.
)                # and
(?![^\/]+$)      # not a path that doesn't contain any '/'
.+\.[^.]+$       # and ends with a dot followed by 1+ non-dot characters
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CNUwfW/2).

Note that the regex on regex101 was modified a bit so that it won't mess with line breaks.

Comment: wow i think this may work - only issue is that now i noticed that the folders all end in / - so if i use your second suggestion, should i change the second to last line to ([^.]+)$ ?

Comment: @StephenBoyle In that case, the regex is even simpler. Updated for you, see if it works.

Comment: thank you! any reason in regex101 the matches return as null? i see the 5 matches but the result is null. when i test this in the system it does not work, so i wonder if this has anything to do with it. I am also waiting to hear from support on exactly what type of regex they support - or how we could troubleshoot easier. thanks so much!

Comment: @StephenBoyle Actually, they do match. I exclusively used lookaheads so the only thing that was matched is `^` (an empty string at the beginning of the line). You can append `.+` to see the full line being matched.

Comment: thank you - yes this does work well in regex101 - i will see what i hear from the app developers - thank you!

Comment: thanks you so much for your help. in going back to the software developer things get slightly more complicated but i am optimistic. Maybe i should update the initial question, ad we are back to no trailing slash on folders and starting with a slash - BUT the monkey wrench is that they also try to match files in addition to full path. so basically i need your initial regex, but add a condition to not match any string that does not contain a slash and ends in .pdf. make sense? so we want to match /path/to/file/something.pdf but not something.pdf

Comment: initial regex was ^(?!(.+?\/)?e-comps\/([^\/\n]+\/)*([^\/\n]*\.pdf)$)(?!([^\/\n]+\/)*([^\/.\n]+)$)(?!([^\/\n]+\/)*([^.\n]+)$)

Comment: should i update the question?

Comment: Yes, please update it.

Comment: thanks so much @InSync - updated. this program is such a pain - i really hope what they are saying is true and this will work!

Comment: Updated. See if it works for you.

Comment: you are fantastic! This works perfectly! thank you for bearing with me while i finally dragged all the correct info out of the developer. this is working! Better yet now i have several examples you have given for me to learn from. Thanks.